# How to avoid updating with NULL values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, model

All. more or less new to MVC so not sure how to handle the issue.

I have data model generated from a database table(approximately 100 columns). The application form is broken up into 6-7 views. The first view creates a new record and inserts it into the database. The rest of the views suppose to gather information from the form and update the created record.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GeneralInfo(ADP.Models.ADPRegistration _registration)
    {
        try
        {

            ADP.Models.IS_WEBEntities _test = new IS_WEBEntities();
            _test.ADPRegistrations.Attach(_registration);
            _test.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(_registration, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            _test.SaveChanges();

            return View("ReferralMethod",_registration);

        }

        catch(Exception er)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This is the general code that updates my table, it is similar across all of the views. The reason for passing the model back to the view is to preserve the ID across the views.

The problem that I have is that, my entity _registration contains all of the table fields, so when the view is posted only the fields in the views get updated, the previous columns are getting NULLs, since they don't exist in the view my guess. I can't seem to enumerate through the database first model as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that when MVC reconstitutes your model in a POSTback, any fields that are not in the form will be NULL in your model.

Your choices are to include the field(s) as hidden in your view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SomeValue)
```

Or update the model after post, but prior to passing it to your validation & repository layers:

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("Name", new ValueProviderResult("Some string",string.Empty,new CultureInfo("en-US")));
```